# Nashorn/Rhino to convert a string from Java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, rhino, nashorn

I'm using **Play Framework** and I have a .java Controller file in which I obtain an array of strings. I want to **pass this Java array into an html file that will use Javascript** in order to plot the data using **Flot Charts**. This data "transfer" is done in the render. It is something like this:

```
String[] array = new String[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Sample sample : list) {
    array[i++] = sample.getContent();
}
render(array);
```

But then when I'm unable to call this variable in the .html file inside the views folder. If I use ${array}, Firebug tells me that it does not recognize it as a valid JS String array. I've read that Rhino or Nashorn could do the trick, but I do not know if they are the best and simplest option. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: convert it to json and feed that to js, json makes valid js literals. Rhino might still have x.toSource(). which would also work...

Comment: Is it easy or do you have any example of how to do it? It might help me, thanks! :)

Comment: i only roll in JS, but i am willing to bet java has a JSON library available that would work, likely with some examples and stuff.

Comment: @dandavis boon might be the java JSON library you're looking for... https://github.com/boonproject/boon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with **Play Framework** but I'm doing similar stuff using **SparkJava** in both java and javascript (using Nashorn).

I would suggest to use Boon library to generate json: https://github.com/boonproject/boon.

Here's a small Nashorn snippet to get you up to speed, easily adaptable to java:

```
// 1st we create a factory to serialize json out
var jso = new org.boon.json.JsonSerializerFactory().create();
// 2nd we directly use boon on array variable. Boon supports out of the box many pure java objects
jso.serialize(o);
```

In your specific case, you'll need to configure Play output for that particular render as `application/json` and possibly use `render(jso.serialize(o));` in place of the small snippet I gave.